# Linux sh+expect script for cisco devices static route change

Tags: linux, shell, expect, cisco

I've got following scripts and now I faced following problem in some network changes using this script.

**.sh script**

```
 echo -n "Enter the SSH username :"
 read -e username
 echo -ne '\n'
 echo -n "Enter the SSH password :"
 read -s -e password
 echo -ne '\n'
 for device in `cat /var/scripts/list.txt`; do
 /var/scripts/config_changer_multi_device/configure-cisco.exp $device $password $username ;
 done
```

and following .expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

 set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
 set username [lindex $argv 2]
 set password [lindex $argv 1]
 
 send_user "\n"
 send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"
 send_user "\n"
 
 spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname

 expect {
 timeout { send_user "\nTimeout Exceeded - Check Host\n"; exit 1 }
 eof { send_user "\nSSH Connection To $hostname Failed\n"; exit 1 }
 "*#" {}
 "*assword:" {
 send "$password\n"
 }
 }
 
 expect "*#"
 send "enable\n"
 expect "*#"
 send "conf t\n"
 expect "(config)#"
 send "ip route 8.8.8.8 255.255.255.255 $gateway\n"
 expect "(config)#"

 send "exit\n"
 expect "*#"
 send "write mem\n"
 expect "*#"
 send "exit\n"
 expect ":~\$"
 exit
```

I run the .sh script providing user login and password for ssh connection.
This is working fine when I have static gateway instead of variable. What I want to have is to in place where is static route adding have variable $gateway that gets a value from file.
For example If I have file list.txt with router IP 10.100.100.50 I want to script gets also first value from file gateway.txt then second position from list.txt and gateway.txt and so on because on every router gateway IP is another.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net . Read  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . `lso first value from file gateway.txt then second position from list.txt` _Then_ read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/how-to-read-from-two-input-files-using-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Enter the SSH username : " username
read -p "Enter the SSH password : " -s -e password

cd /var/scripts      # or perhaps: cd "$(dirname "$0")"

while IFS=$'\t' read -r device gateway; do
    ./config_changer_multi_device/configure-cisco.exp "$device" "$gateway" "$password" "$username"
done < <(
    paste ./list.txt ./gateway.txt
)
```

---

To add a little security, so the password does not show up in the `ps` output for anyone to see:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Enter the SSH username : " username
read -p "Enter the SSH password : " -s -e password
export username password

cd /var/scripts      # or perhaps: cd "$(dirname "$0")"

while IFS=$'\t' read -r device gateway; do
    ./config_changer_multi_device/configure-cisco.exp "$device" "$gateway"
done < <(
    paste ./list.txt ./gateway.txt
)
```

And the expect script looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

lassign $argv hostname gateway
set username $env(username)
set password $env(password)

# ...
```